# If the limit of power series exists, it converges.

Tags: analysis, power-series

Let $f(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ converges on $(-R, R)$.
Does $\sum a_n R^n$ converge if $\lim _{x \to R-} f(x)$ exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x)^n$$
This converges to $\frac1{1+x}$ on $(-1,1)$. Thus:
$$\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\frac12$$
However:
$$f(-1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n$$
is $1-1+1-1+\dotsb$, which diverges. (It doesn't diverge to *infinity*, and I believe that no counterexample can diverge to infinity, but I'm not sure.)